# Do SMTP services need to be installed for a web app to send emails via a mail server on another box?

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-4, smtp

I am having problems with sending emails from an ASP.NET MVC 4 app.  I am getting the dreaded:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:25
```

The client's mail server is on another box.  I have the correct host name and I can ping it.  I can also use telnet to show that the mailserver is ready and listening on port 25.

In my web.config file, I have the following:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="support@myclient.co.uk">
        <network host="mailserver1" clientDomain="OfficeNetwork.local" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

However, I still get the error above, as if it was trying to find a mailserver on the local machine.

Why?

Not being an expert on IIS or mail servers, do I need to add anything to the default configurtion so that my web app, running on the web server, can use the mailserver that is on another box?  Ie, is there an SMTP service I need to install for this to happen?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you send the email? I don't see an issue with your `web.config`.

Comment: @cheesemacfly:  thanks for looking.  See my answer for why one should leave this to the network guy.

Comment: I just saw your solution but just because I am curious, when you said `I can also use telnet to show that the mailserver is ready` did you actually go to the end of the process and sent an email with no authentication or not?

Comment: @cheesemacfly:  no, I just did telnet mysmtpserver 25

Comment: So probably the authentication was there from the beginning, that's why your configuration wasn't working! Blame the network guy!! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add SMTP as a new role in IIS. Its fairly easy.
[This should get you started](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/configure-smtp-e-mail-in-iis-7-and-above)

Don't forget to check the service has started and running.

Comment: thanks for that, I will have a look at it at some stage in my life.  Right now I am rueing two lost days.

Answer (score 0):

The network guy came back and solved it.  However, I have no idea why it works.

All he did was create a user and password on the mail server that I added to the  tag and voila all problems disappear.  I suspect it is down to how they have security configured for the mail server and they aren't telling me... Alternatively, they don't have a clue either and either got lucky and someone told them to try that.

So another day older and not even a little bit wiser.  Just deeper in debt.  But not to the network guy.